# How can I write a PLSQL to return SYSDATE plus 8 business days?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I write a PLSQL statement to return `SYSDATE` plus 8 business days? 
ComputerTIME + 8 BusinessDays
"ORACLE" DataBase

For example: today is 08/01/2018 -> 8 business day will be 08/13/2018

Comment: Why do you need PL/SQL for this? Does 8 business days mean exclude Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: I have an assignment  where I need return the days 8 from SYSDATE -> Correct not Saturday and Sundays -> For example Today is 08/01/2018 -> 8 business day will the date 08/13/2018.

Comment: What about public holidays?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to have PL/SQL for this? With a SQL query, you would be able to achieve the results, then why to have PL/SQL? PL/SQL is required when the expected results are not possible to achieve with SQL

Try the following, make necessary changes as per your requirement.

```
WITH t
     AS (    SELECT SYSDATE + LEVEL AS dt
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31)
SELECT (TO_CHAR (dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'))
  FROM t
 WHERE     TO_CHAR (dt, 'Dy') NOT IN ('Sat',
                                      'Sun',
                                      'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
       AND dt > SYSDATE + 8
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f4094/1)

Or

```
WITH t
     AS (    SELECT SYSDATE + LEVEL AS dt
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31)
SELECT MIN (
          TO_CHAR (dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'))
  FROM t
 WHERE     TO_CHAR (dt, 'Dy') NOT IN ('Sat',
                                      'Sun',
                                      'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
       AND dt > SYSDATE + 8
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/16d8a/1)

If your assignment is to use PL/SQL, use the below to get the desired output.

```
DECLARE
   v_dt   VARCHAR2 (32);
BEGIN
   WITH t
        AS (    SELECT SYSDATE + LEVEL AS dt
                  FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31)
   SELECT MIN (
             TO_CHAR (dt,
                      'DD-MON-YYYY fmDay',
                      'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'))
     INTO v_dt
     FROM t
    WHERE     TO_CHAR (dt, 'Dy') NOT IN ('Sat',
                                         'Sun',
                                         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
          AND dt > SYSDATE + 8;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_dt);
   RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Result of `TO_CHAR (dt, 'Dy')` depends on current user session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE`, so your solution may not work.

Comment: user75ponic...Question.. you have SELECT MIN (.... FROM t ....What is the reason to call it "t" ?

Comment: @JLSG To get the minimum date or the first date from the list of dates.

Comment: @JLSG Hope I have made it clear, otherwise please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You may directly accomplish the next business date, eight day after the current date by the following SQL SELECT statement :

```
select trunc(sysdate) + rn as eight_next_business_day
  from
(
 select sum(dy) over (order by rn) sm, rn
   from
   (
    select (case when to_char(sysdate+level-1,'D','nls_date_language=turkish') in (6,7)
                 then 0
                 else 1 end ) as dy,
           row_number() over (order by level) as rn 
      from dual
   connect by level <= 31
   ) 
)
where sm = 8;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ab5b30/486)

P.S.

*the value for the argument of **nls_date_language** and whose respective returning values ( **6** and **7** in my case ) might be changed due to your location.*